# how to get the future result in whenComplete

Tags: flutter

Now I am using this code to get a api response from server, when the response complete,  I want to do some logic, this is my code:

```
Future<Response> res= refreshAuthToken(dio, userName, password, response);
        res.whenComplete(() => {
         storage.write(key: "refreshTimes", value: "0")
        });
        return res;
```

first I send a http request to server, then when the response complete, I want to do some logic accord the `Response`, finnaly return the Future result. But my problem is I do not know how to get the response result in whenComplete function, is it possible to using the response result in whenComplete? How to get he response? like:

```
res.whenComplete((response) => {
      storage.write(key: "refreshTimes", value:response.getxxxxxx")
 });
```

Comment: Use then((response) {...}) instead of whenComplete(). It's a good practice to use whenComplete() if you don't care about the future's value, otherwise use then().

`Future<R> then<R>(FutureOr<R> onValue(T value), {Function? onError});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await refreshAuthToken(dio, userName, password, response).then((Response res) {
   // add your logic here.
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `then()` instead of `whenComplete()`.

For Example -

```
MyFutureExample().then((response) {
  // add the logic in here
});
```

The `then()` is fired with it's logic when `MyFutureExample()` completed.